# Bash JSON processing - How to test if all objects in array have satisfied condition

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to write a bash function that would parse a json response and assert if an array of objects all satisfy some condition, but I'm getting nowhere with testing that state.

Exemplary JSON after initial transformations:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Org1",
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "key": "Org2",
    "value": false
  }
]
```

The condition is to have all elements (no matter the length of the array) to have value == true.

I'm doing the JSON transformations using jq, but I have no idea how to either store the result in a bash var so I could loop throw the elements or reduce the array to a single value that I could parse directly in an if statement.

Could anyone help?

Comment: `echo "$json" | jq 'all(.value)'` tests the value property of each object in the array are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `all` function to reduce an array of Booleans* to `true` if all the Booleans are true. `jq` will output that value, which you can capture using command substitution.

```
result=$(jq 'map(.value) | all' tmp.json)
```

You may not need the actual output, though. It may be sufficient to use the `--exit-status` option (short form `-e`) to test if `jq` *would* return `true` or not.

```
if jq -e 'map(.value) | all' tmp.json > /dev/null; then
   echo "All were true"
else
   echo "At least one was false"
fi
```

---

* Among other things; see @peak's comment below

Comment: Technically, and the documentation notwithstanding, the `all` family of filters uses truthiness rather than `true` as the criterion. Consider e.g. `all(1;.)` #=> true ;
`all(nan;.)` #=> true ;
`all(empty;.)` #=> true ;
`all(null;.)` #=> false ;

Comment: Holy cow, I did not see this `all` function. Thank you very much for that one!